# How do I change awn dialect applet style?

Tags: customization, awn

I've just installed AWN and I want to customize it: I don't like the look of dialect applet.

How do I change it's appearance? It would be great if I can change from flags to just letters.

Comment: not sure if that's a Ubuntu related question..

Comment: @shookees - AWN is a third-party piece of software available either directly via 12.04 in the repo or via PPA in later versions.  Yes its on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Changing the flag

I've got a british keyboard layout and hence AWN with the dialect icon looks like this:

[image: pic]

You can with a bit of graphics editing change the flag to text - for example:

[image: pic]

As you can see the "keyboard" dialect icon now has "GB"

All of the flags pictures are found in the folder `/usr/share/avant-window-navigator/applets/dialect/icons`

Look for your flag using your file-manager and find the file-name.  For me, the british flag is `gb.png`.

Lets backup this image first:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/avant-window-navigator/applets/dialect/icons/gb.png ~/
```

This will copy the file to your home folder.

Next using your favourite editor - mine is Gimp, create an image that is 60x40 px in size.

Make sure that the background colour is set to transparent - you can do this in Gimp when creating a new image by clicking the advanced options.

Then add your text to the new transparent image - here I used bold font SANs 24px.

Export your image as `gb.png` to your pictures folder.

Then overwrite your old image with your new image i.e.

```
sudo cp ~/Pictures/gb.png /usr/share/avant-window-navigator/applets/dialect/icons/gb.png
```

To refresh your dialect icon - remove the applet and re-add it.

#### drag and drop

Don't forget - changing the actual base icon is simple as well...

Changing the icon in AWN is a drag-and-drop away:

[image: Imgur]

Thus you can both have a text based "flag" as well as a brand new icon.